# Check Login information from web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

There is a login page in aspx.net that asks the user to enter in their username and what authorization level they are.

My question is once they do that I have to read from that and check what they entered from a sql database with all the possible usernames and authorizations. Problem is the login page is in aspx.net and the code to check the login information is in regular .cs file.

If someone can look over my code and tell me what I am doing wrong and possibly give me a better code or fix what I have that would be great!

And sorry about the errors and confusion, I am new to coding!

Here is what I have so far:

```
public bool getCredentials(string UserName, string Authlvl)
    {

        bool valid = false;

        string loginSQL = "SELECT COUNT FROM user_verification WHERE userID = '" + UserName + "' AND auth_lvl = '" + Authlvl + "'";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(loginSQL, dB.Connect());

        try
        {
            int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            if (rowCount >= 1)
            {
                valid = true;
            }

            else if (rowCount <= 0)
            {
                valid = false;
            }
        }

        catch
        {
        }

        return valid;
    }

    public void getInfo(string _Username, string Authlvl)
    {
        string selectAllSql = "Select auth_lvl FROM user_verification WHERE userID = '" + UserName + "'AND auth_lvl = '" + Authlvl
             + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectAllSql, dB.Connect());
        Authlvl = "";

        SqlDataReader reader;

        try
        {
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                UserName.Text = reader["username"].ToString();
                Authlvl.Text = reader["auth_lvl"].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (new Exception("" + ex));
        }
    }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'import_logDataSet.DB_tables' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.dB_tablesTableAdapter.Fill(this.import_logDataSet.DB_tables);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        save.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clears all text in text box
         ID.Clear();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string str = @"";
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
        process.Start(); 
    }

    private void ID_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;
        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 13 && e.KeyChar < 65 || e.KeyChar > 122)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("ExporterOutput.txt");
        sw.WriteLine(ID.Text);
        sw.Close();
    }
    private void OutputBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Here is the information you input: ");
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("ExporterOutput.txt");
        sw.WriteLine(ID.Text, UserName.Text, Authlvl.Text, comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text, FolderDrop.Text);
        sw.Close();
    }

    private void Help_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
        Help.LinkVisited = true;
    }

    private void save_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please post whatever errors you are seeing. Also, the ASPX file would be useful to help diagnose is there is a problem between it and the code-behind page.

Comment: Well I have bene researching it and a lot of things I am finding are saying to use the isPostBack property to read from the .net file. I just want to read the login information on my file then check if it is on the sql database.

Comment: the aspx file works fine. It is just a login page. the web page comes up and the user can choose between three pages to go to and the pages are all in aspx.vb but the page I created is just cs not aspx.cs. So I am having a problem linking the login page to the .cs file so that when the user clicks on that option it will go to my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `UserID` is a numeric field, `UserID = UserName` will not work.

**EDIT**

I think the problem is with your select statement. `COUNT` is a function and requires an argument. Try something like this instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_verification [rest of your query]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Your website is in grave danger of being hacked**.  You have a SQL Injection vulnerability in your code.  You should resolve that before you do anything else. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx
2. It's asp.net not aspx.net

I am unclear on what you question is.  Are you tyring to access information that is on your aspx page from your code behind?  If so, you just need to reference the textbox in your code behind:

aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb_User" runat="server" />
```

aspx.cs:

```
string user = tb_User.Text;
```

From what I can tell you are not calling `getCredentials` or `getInfo` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Yes I am not in asp.net at all I made a console application in c#. Sorry it is all confusing I am new to this so I am not sure about all the terms but it was just how I could get the information but I think (and you verified) that I wrote that incorrectly. Any suggestions?

Comment: You will need to make calls to `getCredentials` and `getInfo`.  Right now you have them defined but they are never run.  Where you calls them depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to call them from an event, but I can't say for sure.